# Why it is not possible to create directly an array of Functions in java?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

I am trying to create an array of functions to pass to a method:

```
private void test(Function<?,?>... fns) {
        return;
    }
```

In order to do so, I can create the array, and add objects one by one with:

```
Function<A, B>[] fnArr = new Function[10];
fnArr[0] = Class1::staticMethod1;
fnArr[1] = Class1::staticMethod2;
fnArr[2] = Class1::staticMethod3;
...
```

But when I try to to this while initializing array:

```
Function<A, B>[] fnArr = new Function<A, B>[] { Class1::staticMethod1}
```

I get following error:

> Cannot create a generic array of Function

Why is this? How can I avoid having a lot of lines to initialize the array by adding objects 1 by 1?

**Note** I need a solution for **java8**

Comment: There is no type-safe way to do this. Arrays and generics do not mix well.

Comment: You can, however, use `test(Class1::method1, Class2::method2)`. Consider `@SafeVarargs`.